# Rails how to validate file format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I validate my file fields for the correct format?

I want the image field to validate that it is a .png, .jpg, .jpeg.

And the flv that it has the ending .flv

And the quicktime that it have the ending .mov

And how do I create error messages to tell that the field is not valid.

My simple_form_for:

```
<%= f.input :name, :label => 'Navn', :required => true %><br />
<%= f.label :tekst %><br />
<%= f.text_area :text, :label => 'Text', :size => '12x12' %><br />
<%= f.label "Upload billede - kræves" %><br />
<%= f.input :image, :label => '', :required => true %><br />
<%= f.label "Upload flv - kræves" %><br />
<%= f.input :flv, :label => '', :required => true %><br />
<%= f.label "Upload Quicktime - kræves"  %><br />
<%= f.input :quicktime, :label => '', :required => true %><br />
<%= f.button :submit, :value => 'Create movie' %>
```

**Update:**

I have figure out how to validate the .mov and .flv fields:

```
validates_format_of :flv, 
:with => %r{\.flv$}i, :message => "file must be in .flv format"

validates_format_of :mov, 
:with => %r{\.mov$}i, :message => "file must be in .mov format"
```

I just don´t have found a solution to validate the image.

My controller:

```
def savenew
    @photographer = Photographer.new(params[:photographer]) 
    @photographer.sort_order = Photographer.count + 1

    if @photographer.save   
      redirect_to :action => 'list', :id => params[:id]
      flash[:notice] = "Movie #{@photographer.name} is created"
    else    
      render 'create', :id => params[:id]             
    end                                 
end
```

Comment: I don't know rails, so leaving this as a comment, but this link may be of interest: http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/38613644108f447a?fwc=1

Comment: Also, I would suggest removing the stuff about file *extensions*.  Validating a format is very different from validating an extension.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to continue as with flv and mov, you could do:

```
validates_format_of :image, :with => %r{\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$}i, :message => "whatever"
```

*but* please be aware that this would only validate that the filename would end in a specific string. These don't validate that the actual file is a real PNG (or whatever format). So someone could still just upload a zipfile with extension ".png".

Comment: Now if both .mov and .flv is valid and the image is not valid it renders the form again, but all the error messages are displayed. Instead of only a error message for the image. I have posted my controller in my question. And why are the file fields always cleared? When it is not valid.