# How to validate a URL must be .gif, .jpg, or .png in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following code is supposed to validate if the image_url submitted ends with .gif, .jpg, or .png. However, I'm not sure I understand how this piece of code `"%r{\.(gif|jpg|png)\Z}i"` validates the format.

```
# Sample Code:
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :title, :description, :image_url, presence: true
    validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
    validates :title, uniqueness: true
    validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: { with: %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)\Z}i, message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.'
    }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all this should change

```
 validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: { with: %r{.(gif|jpg|png)\Z}i, message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.' }
```

i think if your image is the field, you should do this

```
 validates :image, allow_blank: true, format: { with: %r{.(gif|jpg|png)\Z}i, message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.' }
```

If it is image_url. Then you are absolutely correct.

it works like this it checks the ending(format) of file to be like either gif, jpg or png.  it wont work if your file do not have these extensions.

Follow this link please:

[Rails how to validate file format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540601/rails-how-to-validate-file-format)

Comment: Just to inform you i didn't test your regex which validates the file. Hope it is correct. Link has the regex. You can use that too kindly